# Add node to multilevel linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I apologize for this noob question but I'm really struggling with this. I have a linked list with two different links: Next and sort. I want to add to the front with next but add in increasing order to sort. However whenever I try and add to sort I get a segfault and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to access them in a way that they act as two distinct linked lists with the same data but in a different order.

this is my list:

```
typedef struct NODE { 
    value_t value;
    key_t key;
    struct NODE * next; 
    struct NODE * sort;
} Node;
```

and this is how I'm trying to write to it

```
Node * add_sorted(Node ** head, int value, key_t key){
    Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->sort->value = value;
        new_node->sort->key = key;
        new_node->sort = *head; 
        *head = new_node;
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

thank you in advance for enduring my ignorance

Comment: Is that `Node` structure your idea or something given to you that you are required to use?

Comment: @ommy Davies These statements new_node->sort->value = value;
        new_node->sort->key = key; result in undefined behavior because the data member sort was not initialized.

Comment: It's for a class. I would ask my TA for help but due to recent events, there is no way to contact anyone for clarification. But yes this is necessary for the assignment

Comment: @ommy Davies The assignment does not make sense because the head node can be only one. There can not be the same head node for sorted and unsorted list.

Comment: Just to clarify again. I understand that you need both a sorted and an unsorted list. But are you actually saying that that exact structure was given to you and cannot be changed? Because it isn't a natural way to do it (and arguably is not possible).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign value to somewhere that you did not initialize in address space.

```
new_node->sort->value = value; 
new_node->sort->key = key;
```

In this part, you did not create *sort but it is declared like it is there. Creating new_node does not mean there is a *sort. Because it is a pointer. In this case, it does not point anywhere but void.

I do not know if it is related to your problem but I think you need to solve that one too.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm starting to understand where I went wrong here. So how specifically can I initialize the sort pointer?

Comment: Just like what you did in creating new_node! new_node->sort = malloc(sizeof(Node)). After that you can assign something to new_node->sort using new_node->sort->value = value By the way, I strongly recommend you to use paper and pencil. Draw the steps and visualize the code you wrote in computer. It takes a little time to understand how data structures work and how pointers behave.

Comment: @TommyDavies This does not make sense. Each node can be either sorted in the list or unsorted. It can not be in two states simultaneously. Write in paper how you imagine such a list.

Answer (score 0):

In adding, `new_node->sort = *head;` doesn't have any sense. Because, previous setting of attribute `sort` will be erased.

Answer (score 0):

first you are assigning value to a pointer without allocating memory for it or initializing it.

this should work:

```
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->sort = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new_node->sort->value = value;
        new_node->sort->key = key;
        new_node->sort = *head; 
        *head = new_node;
    }
```

also note that your function argument `int value` has different type from the member you are assigning it to.(`value_t value`)

also I think here `new_node->sort = *head;` you meant `new_node->next = *head;` ,because with this assignment data ,you assigned to fields of sort will be lost.